# Array.filter is not returning the required output

Tags: javascript

I am having nested array of data.I am able to get the first set of data based on my condition but when I am applying array.filter on this result set it is not giving me the expected result.

Below is array of data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Date": "02/04/2019",
      "Total": "1000",
      "Success": "850",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [
        {
          "name": "Reason1",
          "Count": 2,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Reason2",
          "Count": 6,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "03/04/2019",
      "Total": "800",
      "Success": "750",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [
        {
          "name": "Reason1",
          "Count": 3,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Reason2",
          "Count": 1,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

First I have applied the below array.filter to get the FailureDetails based on date:

```
 var filtered = data
          .filter(value => data.Date == "02/04/2019")
          .map(e => e.FailureDeatils);
```

This is giving me Failure Details with Description but now on Reason Id ,i want to get the Description but it is not working and returning the result as "undefined"

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong??

Comment: Use `value.Date` instead of `data.Date`

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `value.Date` instead of `data.Date` because `value` reference to each object in the `data` array:

```js
var data = [{
  "Date": "02/04/2019",
  "Total": "1000",
  "Success": "850",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
    "name": "Reason1",
    "Count": 2,
    "Description": [{
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }, {
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Reason2",
    "Count": 6,
    "Description": [{
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }, {
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "Date": "03/04/2019",
  "Total": "800",
  "Success": "750",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
    "name": "Reason1",
    "Count": 3,
    "Description": [{
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }, {
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Reason2",
    "Count": 1,
    "Description": [{
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }, {
      "DescriptionID": "01",
      "Status": "Failure Point1"
    }]
  }]
}];


var filtered = data
  .filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019")
  .map(e => e.FailureDeatils);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you mean `value.Date` not `data.Date`.

```
.filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019")
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the wrong variable in the filter:

**should be:**

`const filtered = data.filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019").map(e => e.FailureDeatils);`

**and not:**

`const filtered = data.filter(value => data.Date == "02/04/2019").map(e => e.FailureDeatils);`

Here the working **example** based on your code:

```js
const object = {
        "data": [
          {
            "Date": "02/04/2019",
            "Total": "1000",
            "Success": "850",
            "Failure": "150",
            "FailureDeatils": [
              {
                "name": "Reason1",
                "Count": 2,
                "Description": [
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  },
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "Reason2",
                "Count": 6,
                "Description": [
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  },
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Date": "03/04/2019",
            "Total": "800",
            "Success": "750",
            "Failure": "150",
            "FailureDeatils": [
              {
                "name": "Reason1",
                "Count": 3,
                "Description": [
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  },
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "Reason2",
                "Count": 1,
                "Description": [
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  },
                  {
                    "DescriptionID": "01",
                    "Status": "Failure Point1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    
    const filtered = object.data.filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019").map(e => e.FailureDeatils);
    
    console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: yes!! correct....i am able to get this set of arrayResult with const filtered = data.filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019").map(e => e.FailureDeatils) but  again from the resultant i need to have an array of description based on name i.e. Reason1 or Reason2 ....that is what I am unable to retrieve.